# How to execute a specific js request without loading the whole web page?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to get a single element from the [webpage](https://www.rbc.ru/society/05/01/2018/5a4e9de19a7947e2bef693a1?from=main) - a number of views (`2128` digit on the upper left side near the eye image right now). The number is a result of some javascript function so it absents in the source page code, and I cannot get it with http request. I wouldn't like to download the whole page with Selenium webdriver either. Is there any way to run a single javascript code from the page without downloading it?

Comment: I certainly hope not.

Comment: It depends where the javascript gets it from; with any luck it pulls it from some REST / GraphQL microservice and you could get it directly. Worst case, yes, it may depend on downloading the whole page first. Only way to know is to dig into the javascript and figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @JeffC Sorry I didn't find any relevant cases though spent the whole day googling for it. All examples were about running JS code from Selenium webdriver, I decided not to put'em here to avoid distraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `selenium` and use `requests` directly, but this would require two steps in this case - get the *short URL value* from the initial webpage first and then get the number of views from a separate endpoint:

```
import re

import requests


pattern = re.compile(r'data-shorturl="https://r.rbc.ru/(.*?)"')
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36'}
    response = session.get("https://www.rbc.ru/society/05/01/2018/5a4e9de19a7947e2bef693a1?from=main")

    short_url = pattern.search(response.text).group(1)

    response = session.get("https://www.rbc.ru/redir/stat/{short_url}".format(short_url=short_url))

    data = response.json()
    print(data["show"])
```

Currently prints `7712`.

Note that using a regex to extract the short URL value in this case is perfectly okay, since we are not parsing HTML markup and structure with regular expressions but rather just extracting a specific part of a URL string somewhere in the document.

Comment: could you tell please how did you guess the link for the second request - `https://www.rbc.ru/redir/stat/`?

Comment: @Vlad just opened the browser developer tools - Network tab and went through the XHR request content. It was sort of a shot in the dark but worked. Thanks.